# Selenium Won't Iterate Through All Pages Using XPATH. Keep receiving "NoSuchElementException" error

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Currently the below code gets to the second page and then I get a "NoSuchElementException" error. I have tried iterating using the HREF as well. The link text works slightly better but I encounter issues when I reach the "..." portion of the iteration, so would prefer to stick with the XPATH. Feel like I have tried everything.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://www.sec.state.ma.us/LobbyistPublicSearch/Default.aspx'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element('id','ContentPlaceHolder1_rdbSearchByType').click()
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'p3'))
select.select_by_value('2020')
driver.find_element('id','ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch').click()
find_table = driver.find_element(By.ID,'ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSearchResultByTypeAndCategory_grdvSearchResultByTypeAndCategory')

xpath_string = """//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSearchResultByTypeAndCategory_grdvSearchResultByTypeAndCategory"]/tbody/tr[98]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"""
all_xpath = []
for i in range(1,all_pages):
    pn = str(i + 1)
    links_list_sliced = list(xpath_string)
    links_list_sliced[131] = pn
    joined_links = ''.join(links_list_sliced)
    all_xpath.append(joined_links)
    
for l in all_xpath:
    current_page_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, l)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((current_page_element))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

@David Kahn, Seems the number of elements on each page are different. So in your xpath `tr[98]` is not always the case. You can do the following changes and it should work.

Your xpath_string should be the following. Where I have removed the dependency on position of the page numbers on 98th row of the table.

```
xpath_string = """//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucSearchResultByTypeAndCategory_grdvSearchResultByTypeAndCategory"]/tbody/tr[@align="center"]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"""
```

For this to work you need to change the following line in your for loop:

```
links_list_sliced[131] = pn
```

to:

```
links_list_sliced[144] = pn
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks @ketanvj! It seems to work until it needs to click on page 13 at which point it skips to page 21 and then ends the loop without getting to the final page which is page 37. any suggestions? Besides the tr[n] that you mentioned, the rest of the XPATH seems to stay consistent.

Comment: EDIT: It seems to work until it needs to click on page 12**